# How to fix YAML File Transform Task when "changes are already present"?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We are starting with Azure Pipelines (YAML) and we are experiencing the following error during a FileTransform task:

```
##[error]Unable to apply transformation for the given package - Changes are already present in the package.
```

The result is that no transformation is taking place and the deployed config matches the Release.config

This is an ASP.NET web app with a Web.Config, Web.Stage.config, Web.Release.config etc.

The end goal is to set different stages and apply the corresponding transformations with the config files. But for now, **I just would like to get the "Release" build and apply the "Stage" transformation**, to make sure this task works.

If it helps, this is a snippet of the YAML:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
```

...

```
task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

...

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: FileTransform@2
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    xmlTransformationRules: '-transform **\*.Stage.config -xml **\*.config'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Microsoft Partner Network(blablabla)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'mywebapp'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Update:
The final web.config file contains a connection string like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String_0)" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Here is the log for the build step. You can see transformaton is hapenning during build.

[image: Here is the log for the build step.]
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested and found above error will occur in below cases.

1, When no configuration file or transform file were found against the file pattern in `xmlTransformationRules`. This could be the file pattern is incorrect or the transform file/configuration file does not exist in the package.

2, When the configuration file and transform file are not in the same folder within the specified package.

The `xmlTransformationRules` in above yaml was working in my test. So you need to check if 
configuration file and transform file are in different folders. You need to make sure they are in the same folder for XML transformation to take effect.

See the [XML transformation notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-transformation-notes)
 for more information.

**Update**:

By default web.config file will be transformed against the web.{buildConfiguration}.config during building.

You can disable vsbuild task to transform web.config by passing `/p:IsTransformWebConfigDisabled=true` to `msbuildArgs` attribute. See below example:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:IsTransformWebConfigDisabled=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: I verified that all files in my project are in the same folder. Web.config, Web.Debug.config, Web.Stage.config, Web.Release.config, etc.

Comment: I also verified that when I comment out the transformation task, the final deployed web.config file matches the buildConfiguration variable.
What could I do to better understand and isolate the problem?

Comment: By default web.config file will be transformed against the web.{buildConfiguration}.config during building. You can disable vsbuild task to transform web.config by seting `IsTransformWebConfigDisabled` to true. See above update.

Comment: Still not there. I double checked on the build log "IsTransformWebConfigDisabled" is now there, as you suggest.

Comment: One hint is that I can see also on the log a "PreTransformWebConfig" executed, and it seems the transformation is still hapenning. That would tell me transformation is not entirely disabled by msbuild. What do you think?

Comment: I cannot find `PreTransformWebConfig` in my build log. You can download the artfiacts to you local machine to check if the transformation is executed on releas.config. Please check the .csproj file to see if there is any msbuild target configured to transform the config file. If it is all ok. You can have a try using this propertry `/p:ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled=false /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=false`. It was working on my test project too.

Comment: I was not able to find any Transformation related target on the csproj... I checked the final artifact web.config file and it seems some pre transformation was done, but it is not complete. Check the update on original question.